# Event on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to use jQuery to make certain actions happen when someone presses a key, for example 'x'.

Here's my code:

```
.keydown(function(event) {
  var keycode = ""
    function getKey(e) {
      keycode = e.keyCode;
    };
    if (keycode === 88) {
       $('ryu-still').hide();
       $('.ryu-cool').show();
    };
});
```

What I'm trying to do, is that in the event that "x" is pressed, it will hide that section, and show another section. So I've added a function to capture what key is being pressed, store it, and then check it. If it's an "x", then perform the event.

Please help!

Comment: You don't call your inner function. You don't actually need that inner function. Simply do `if (e.keyCode === 88)` instead.

Comment: @crush I suspect he plans on enhancing the `getKey` function to use `keyCode` or `charCode`, whichever is appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar Well, then all he needs to do is call it before using the value of keyCode. I'd probably make it return the value though, rather than an external variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for keypress event. I hope it helps.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var code = e.which;
  var cxar = String.fromCharCode(code);
  $('body').append(cxar + " = " + code + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click in this window and press any key<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As crush pointed out the inner function is doing nothing. You want something like this:

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 88) {
        console.log("hey, you pressed x");
        $('ryu-still').hide();
        $('.ryu-cool').show();
    };
});
```